# std::thread is not being found on gcc-8.2.2 with flag option -m32. I'm using mingw

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, mingw

[image]

I was trying to compile a cpp program for a school project. It uses libbgi for graphics, which works for 32-bit target. For this project i wanted to add some multithreading with std::thread, but the compiler say i couldn't find std::thread.

I tried a compiler with a lower version, with c++11 support.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(){
    std::thread t([](){
             std::cout << "Hello\n";
        }
    );
    t.join();
}
```

this program compiles fine with -m64, but not with -m32.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text are not accessible, searchable, or easily readable on small screens. Please [edit] the question and augment or replace the image with the text that it contains. The text can be formatted appropriately using the features in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might need to link with `pthread` and use `c++0x`.

`g++ -std=c++0x -m32 main.cpp -pthread -o main`

I recreated your error and it was solved using these flags.